# Python tkinter window resizes, but widgets never change or move

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Python beginner. I placed a scrollbar widget in window and that works, but no matter what I do I can't get the scrollbox widget to change size. Could go with a larger scrollbox or for it to resize when the window resizes, but can't figure out how to force either to happen. Tried lots of different solutions, but feels like the grid and canvas are defaulting to a size and can't figure out how to change that. Help would be appreciated.  Code is below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import subprocess

class Scrollable(tk.Frame):
    """
       Make a frame scrollable with scrollbar on the right.
       After adding or removing widgets to the scrollable frame,
       call the update() method to refresh the scrollable area.
    """

    def __init__(self, frame, width=16):

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y, expand=True)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.__fill_canvas)

        # base class initialization
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, frame)

        # assign this obj (the inner frame) to the windows item of the canvas
        self.windows_item = self.canvas.create_window(0,0, window=self, anchor=tk.NW)


    def __fill_canvas(self, event):
        "Enlarge the windows item to the canvas width"

        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.windows_item, width = canvas_width)

    def update(self):
        "Update the canvas and the scrollregion"

        self.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.windows_item))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("application")
root.geometry('750x800')
dbEnvs = ['a','b']
x = 1

header = ttk.Frame(root)
body = ttk.Frame(root)
footer = ttk.Frame(root)
header.pack(side = "top")
body.pack()
footer.pack(side = "top")


#setup Environment selection 
envLabel = tk.Label(header, text="Environment:")
envLabel.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nw')
dbselection = tk.StringVar()

scrollable_body = Scrollable(body, width=20)
x = 1
for row in range(50):
    checkboxVar = tk.IntVar()
    checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(scrollable_body, text=row, variable=checkboxVar)
    checkbox.var = checkboxVar  # SAVE VARIABLE
    checkbox.grid(row=x, column=1, sticky='w')
    x += 1

scrollable_body.update()

#setup buttons on the bottom
pullBtn = tk.Button(footer, text='Pull')
pullBtn.grid(row=x, column=2, sticky='ew')
buildBtn = tk.Button(footer, text='Build')
buildBtn.grid(row=x, column=3, sticky='ew')
compBtn = tk.Button(footer, text='Compare')
compBtn.grid(row=x, column=4, sticky='ew')


root.mainloop()
```

have tried anchoring, changing the window base size and multiple other things (8 or 19 different items, plus reading lots of posts), but they normally involve packing and since I used grids that normally and ends with more frustration and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole scrollbox to expand to fill the `body` frame, you must instruct `pack` to do that using the `expand` and `fill` options:

```
body.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Another problem is that you're setting `expand` to `True` for the scrollbar. That's probably not something you want to do since it means the skinny scrollbar will be allocated more space than is needed. So, remove that attribute or set it to `False`.

```
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y, expand=False)
```

---

tip: when debugging layout problems, the problems are easier to visualize when you temporarily give each widget a unique color. For example, set the canvas to one color, `body` to another, the instance of `Scrollable` to another, etc. This will let you see which parts are visible, which are growing or shrinking, which are inside the borders of others, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Brian! That solved the problem. You probably recognize this code as I took from a post you wrote years ago and modified it for my requirements. Thanks again.